# Are the set of divisors of $N$ closed under multiplication of a linear combination of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Every integer can be written as the linear combination of two Fibonacci numbers.

For example, if we want to write $N = aF_m + bF_n$, we can choose two Fibonacci numbers, $F_m, F_n$ that are coprime and then solve for $a, b$ using the Extended Euclidean algorithm. Is the converse also true? i.e., Given an integer $N$, does there exist a pair of integers $a,b$ such that all divisors $d$ of $N$ may be written as $d = aF_m + bF_n$?

i.e., Given $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, is there an identity similar to the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity where

$$N = aF_m + bF_n = (aF_r + bF_s)(aF_t + bF_u)$$

for some integers $m, n, r, s, t, u$.

Clearly $a,b$ can be chosen such that $1$ and $d|N$ are represented, at least for the following small examples with $a = 1, b = -2$:

$$
1 = F_4 - 2F_1, \\
2 = F_6 - 2F_4, \\
3 = F_5 - 2F_1, \\
4 = F_6 - 2F_3, \\
5 = F_8 - 2F_6, \\
6 = F_6 - 2F_2, \\
7 = F_7 - 2F_4, \\
8 = F_9 - 2F_7, \\
9 = F_7 - 2F_3, \\
10 = F_6 - 2F_{-2}, \\
11 = F_7 - 2F_1, \\
12 = ? \\
13 = F_{10} - 2F_8, \\
14 = F_6 - 2F_{-4}, \\
15 = F_8 - 2F_4, \\
16 = F_0 - 2F_{-6}, \\
17 = F_8 - 2F_3, \\
18 = F_9 - 2F_6, \\
19 = F_8 - 2F_2, \\
20 = ? \\
21 = F_9 - 2 F_0, \\
22 = ? \\
23 = F_9 - 2F_{-2}, \\
24 = F_9 - 2F_5
$$

Note that we are extending the Fibonacci series in the negative numbers as well (as can be seen with the example for $10, 14, 16, 23$). At least with $N$ up to $11$, we see that all divisors of $N$ can be represented with $a = 1, b = -2$. For the divisors of $12$, the pair $a=1, b = -3$ generates $1, 2, 3, 4, 6$ and $12$. It is necessary that $a,b$ are coprime (so that a prime factor $p$ of $N$ can be represented by $aX + bY = p$).

**Question:** I am asking if we can always find $a,b$ such that all divisors of a given $N$ can be represented as the linear combination $aX + bY$ where $X,Y$ are Fibonacci numbers.

---

***Note:*** For the representations of $12, 20, 22$ and their respective divisors [see this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4734115):

They use different $a, b$ pairs for the representation of the divisors.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain how "$a,b$ can be chosen such that $1, N$ are represented", and what makes you think the answer to your question might be yes? Did you make some successful numerical experiments?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you found such solutions for N = 4, 8, 16? If so, how about N = 6, 24? How many ways are there to obtain for example 1, from two arbitrary (coprime) coefficients?

Comment: Why speak of divisors? Your question is equivalent to the existence, for every integer $M,$ of $a,b$ such that every integer from $1$ to $M$ is of the form $aF_m+bF_n$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: But we need the same $a,b$ for all divisors of $M$ and we don't care if $a,b$ is not a satisfying pair for $d$ if $d$ does not divide $M$. This was motivated by the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity where the set of integers $ma^2 + nb^2$ is closed under multiplication and if we are able to find two such representations of $N$, we could use that to factor $N$. I am wondering if we substitute Fibonacci numbers instead of squares, whether an analogous identity holds.

Comment: @AnneBauval: An example is $15$ in the above table. $1, -2$ is a satisfying pair for $15$ since $1, 3, 5, 15$ can be represented. We don't care that $12$ which is less than $15$ may or may not be representable with $a=1, b=-2$.

Comment: I maintain that if "your" statement (i.e. only for every $k$ dividing $N$) holds for every $N$ then "mine" (i.e. for every $k$ from $1$ to $M$) holds for every $M:$ I apply "yours" to $N=M!.$ So "mine", though seemingly stronger, is actually equivalent.

Comment: I see your point on $M!$. The statement $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that all members of the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, M!\}$ can be represented as $aF_m + bF_n$ for some integers $m, n$ appears to be a stronger conjecture. Can that be proven?

Comment: No it is not stronger, it is equivalent. You don't seem to see my point. Can you please re-read my last comment? I did not consider every $k\le M!$ but every $k\mid M.$ This covers every $k\le M.$

Comment: Ah yes. I see that now.

Comment: Thanks @AnneBauval. I have split the other related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4734115

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147153/discussion-between-vvg-and-anne-bauval).